# Solve homogeneous differential equation when p and q = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

I understand how to use $y = e^{rx}$ for solving homogeneous 2 order differential equation, but can't use this method somehow for $y'' = 0$.

$y'' = r^2e^{rx}$

$r^2e^{rx} = 0$

$r^2 = 0 => r = 0$

General solution of 2 order diff is $y = C_1e^{r_1x} + C_2e^{r_2x}$ We only got one $r$ which is 0, so $y = C_1e^{0x}$ => $y = C_1$

How do I get $y = c_1x + c2$ by this approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution $r=0$ is a twice **repeated** root, so the general solution is actually $$y=(c_1x+c_2)e^{rx}=(c_1x+c_2)e^{0x}=c_1x+c_2$$

You can see this normally since a (homogeneous) linear differential equation of order $2$ must have $2$ linearly independent solutions. You found one solution $y_1(x)=C_1e^{rx}=C_1$. You should think of a second solution $y_2(x)$, linearly independent from $y_1(x)$ i.e. not a constant multiple of $y_1(x)$, that you will guess. The simplest function linearly independent of $y_1(x)$ is $y_2(x)=C_2xe^{rx}$. Then $$y_2''=C_2re^{rx}(rx+2)=0$$ since $r=0$, so $y_2(x)=C_2xe^{rx}=C_2x$ is another solution. Since we can have a maximum of two linearly independent solutions to a second order linear differential equation, that tells us $y_g(x)=C_1+C_2x =c_1x+c_2$, with $C_1=c_2$ and $C_2=c_1$.

Comment: If twice, then I should be getting $ y = C_1 e^{0x} + C_2e^{0x} = C_1 + C_2$. why do you bring $x$ ? I'm just following the idea that general solution to homogeneous differential is $y = C_1 e^{r_1x} + C_2e^{r_2x}$

Comment: @Chemistry no. If the general solution were $y = C_1 + C_2$ you could simply combine the two constants and write $y = C$. You need two linearly independent solutions. It can be better understood by thinking about the solution backwards: if $y'' = 0$, then $y$ is either a constant w.r.t. $x$ or a linear function of $x$.

Comment: From the point of thinking backwards, I get it why it's $c_1x + c2$, I just don't get it that by simply following $C_1e^{r_1x} + C_2e^{r_2x}$, how we end up with $c_1x + c2$

Comment: @Chemistry that's because you don't

Comment: @Chemistry You can only follow that formula when $r_1$ and $r_2$ are distinct, precisely because it is then that $e^{r_1x}$ and $e^{r_2x}$ are *two* linearly independent solutions to a linear differential equation of order *two*. In your case when $r_1=r_2=0$, we see that $e^{r_1x}$ and $e^{r_2x}$ are not linearly independent of each other since they're multiples of each other (i.e. with constant $1$), so your method does not work.